# R: Subset a zoo object?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

Given a date I can access the appropriate element in a zoo vector.
For example:

```
z[as.POSIXct(1213708500, origin="1970-01-01")]
```

this returns

```
2008-06-17 14:15:00 
           -8.28123
```

I would like to get a vector of 30 consecutive elements (ending with the element above).

How do I do that (efficiently) without knowing the time stamp of the starting element?

I know that I can do this with the `window` function, but it requires a start time and an end time.

Comment: Are you trying to do rolling calculations?  If that is the case see `?rollapply`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like

```
ind <- which(index(z)==as.POSIXct(1213708500, origin="1970-01-01")) + seq(-29,0)
```

followed by

```
z[ind]
```

where the `which()` gives you the index of the match, from which you can then pick the thirty consecutive elements by normal indexing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please tell me, if instead of the timestamp (1213708500) I have a vector of timestamps, how can I return a matrix into `ind`?

Comment: Hm, that may "just" be normal vector valued indexing problem. Try looking at `help(match)` / `help("%in%")`.  Also, I really like the xts package for its indexing where you say something like `x["2010-01::2010-06"]` to get six months, and idem for hour/mins/secs/... etc.  Ultimately, that is better because in what we discuss here, you do depend on equality being true somewhere.  That said `min(which(... >= ...))` would work too I suppose.